# Showing that $\mathbb{Z}[\phi]$ is a UFD, where $\phi^2+\phi+1=0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, euclidean-domain

I would like to show that $\mathbb{Z}[\phi]$ is a UFD, where $\phi^2+\phi+1=0$. I started with a division with remainder to determine the irreducibles, but I could not finish that, and I do not know how to approach this problem. Could you provide me with some resources or show how I can solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This ring is the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$. Since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ has class number $1$, its ring of integers is a PID and a UFD.

Comment: I don't know the topic you are referring to. I think I am expected to solve this by defining a norm. I am sort of clueless.

Comment: The standard proof is to show that the ring is a PID. Then it is a UFD of course. But this is just class number $1$ and follows immediately from the fact that $B_K<2$ (Minkowski bound). Alternatively show that every ideal is principal.

Comment: I believe this is the ring of Eisienstein integers where $\phi$ is a primitive cube root of unity. Show this ring is a UFD by showing it is Euclidean: For $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb Z[\phi]$, we can write $\alpha/\beta = p + q\phi, p,q \in \mathbb Q$. Now round $p$ and $q$ to the nearest integers $m,n$ and show that $N[\alpha-(m+n\phi) \beta < N(\beta)$ and thus that $\mathbb Z[\phi]$ has a division algorithm.